# Problems getting data from Firestore to display in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a project with the use of Firebase and I'm having some issues with getting the data inside of my database to display in the DOM due to error "setupFoodGroup is not defined"...This is likely due to a rookie coding error, but I can't seem to work out where I've gone wrong.
Current code as per below:

```
// Get data from database
db.collection('foodgroups').get().then(snapshot => {
    setupFoodGroup(snapshot.docs);
});

// Setting Up Food Lists
const foodList = document.querySelector('.foodGroups');
const setupFoodGroup = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const group = doc.data();
        const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">${group.title}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">${group.content}</p>
                    </>
                </div>
            </li>
        `;
        html += li
    })
    foodGroups.innerHTML = html;
};
```

I'm then wanting to get them displaying inside the following HTML on a display page

```
<div class="card-body">
    <ul class="foodGroups">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Any points would be very much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Try `foodList.innerHTML = html`. Just a typo?

Comment: Your function declared via `const` is **not** hoisted. Try defining it higher up. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init

Comment: And in simpler terms..you are trying to use a function that doesn't exist yet in your code

Comment: Or there you have definition of `setupFoodGroup` in other file and you haven't imported it...